# Bitcoin Core keeps "quitting unexpectedly" or hangs up with the rainbow swirls on my Macbook Air + External SSD

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm running V.20.1 Bitcoin Core on a Mac Book Air. Using an external SSD that's connected via USB C.

In the middle of syncing - at random points in time the Bitcoin Core app "quits unexpectedly". No idea what the cause is. Also random instances of the program hanging with the rainbow swirls. Seeing the error message below. I've already tried deleting the chainstate folder to reindex from the beginning, that hasn't worked.

Seeing this from the debug log:

```
2020-11-26T02:34:13Z LevelDB read failure: Corruption: block checksum mismatch: /Volumes/My Passport/Core/chainstate/031900.ldb
2020-11-26T02:34:13Z Fatal LevelDB error: Corruption: block checksum mismatch: /Volumes/My Passport/Core/chainstate/031900.ldb
2020-11-26T02:34:13Z You can use -debug=leveldb to get more complete diagnostic messages
2020-11-26T02:34:13Z Error: Error reading from database, shutting down.
2020-11-26T02:34:30Z Error reading from database: Fatal LevelDB error: Corruption: block checksum mismatch: /Volumes/My Passport/Core/chainstate/031900.ldb
```

Seeing the below from my system:

```
Process:               Bitcoin-Qt [15232]
Path:                  /Applications/Bitcoin-Qt.app/Contents/MacOS/Bitcoin-Qt
Identifier:            org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt
Version:               0.20.1 (0.20.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Bitcoin-Qt [15232]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-11-25 18:42:07.295 -0800
OS Version:            macOS 11.0.1 (20B29)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.0.1 (18P2561)
Anonymous UUID:        B8752D10-676E-40B9-77CA-DB75279771FD

Sleep/Wake UUID:       02EFAD81-0B12-45C3-8DB0-128B48C3FA3A

Time Awake Since Boot: 14000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        9  b-loadblk

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106dfb1b 0x10ff80000 + 7731995
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106dfaac 0x10ff80000 + 7731884
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106df56e 0x10ff80000 + 7730542
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000010ffafb19 0x10ff80000 + 195353
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000010ffafcfc 0x10ff80000 + 195836
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000010ff957e3 0x10ff80000 + 88035
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000010ff96f50 0x10ff80000 + 94032
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20331631 start + 1

Thread 1:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202ea1fe __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204356b3 __CFSocketManager + 644
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 2:: b-qt-init
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e84fe poll + 10
1   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110834d40 0x10ff80000 + 9129280
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110836167 0x10ff80000 + 9134439
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001107fb65f 0x10ff80000 + 8894047
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106db77c 0x10ff80000 + 7714684
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106de900 0x10ff80000 + 7727360
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e1e7e mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e21f0 mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040ebe7 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040d2ba __CFRunLoopRun + 1315
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2040c6be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22dac36d _NSEventThread + 124
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:: b-scriptch.0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100e182f 0x10ff80000 + 1447983
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102e6114 0x10ff80000 + 3563796
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102afcf6 0x10ff80000 + 3341558
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110661338 0x10ff80000 + 7213880
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 5:: b-scriptch.1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100e182f 0x10ff80000 + 1447983
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102e6114 0x10ff80000 + 3563796
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102afcf6 0x10ff80000 + 3341558
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110661338 0x10ff80000 + 7213880
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 6:: b-scriptch.2
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100e182f 0x10ff80000 + 1447983
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102e6114 0x10ff80000 + 3563796
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102afcf6 0x10ff80000 + 3341558
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110661338 0x10ff80000 + 7213880
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 7:: b-scheduler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e40c6 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203142c5 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 81
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203121bc _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 211
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff202ab8f7 std::__1::recursive_mutex::lock() + 9
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ba6c4 0x10ff80000 + 1287876
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011042b7c6 0x10ff80000 + 4896710
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102f98db 0x10ff80000 + 3643611
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001105bcce7 0x10ff80000 + 6540519
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001105bc2f5 0x10ff80000 + 6537973
9   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ddfc3 0x10ff80000 + 1433539
10  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100e7fa4 0x10ff80000 + 1474468
11  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110661338 0x10ff80000 + 7213880
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff2027dcf2 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 18
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110653727 0x10ff80000 + 7157543
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106536b9 0x10ff80000 + 7157433
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106537ea 0x10ff80000 + 7157738
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 9 Crashed:: b-loadblk
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e8462 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316610 pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff20269720 abort + 120
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057c509 0x10ff80000 + 6276361
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057a9cc 0x10ff80000 + 6269388
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057abd7 0x10ff80000 + 6269911
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057a9cc 0x10ff80000 + 6269388
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057b6bb 0x10ff80000 + 6272699
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011057c1e0 0x10ff80000 + 6275552
9   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011009ad53 0x10ff80000 + 1158483
10  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102b0bb5 0x10ff80000 + 3345333
11  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102bafa2 0x10ff80000 + 3387298
12  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102bc8d5 0x10ff80000 + 3393749
13  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102be61e 0x10ff80000 + 3401246
14  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001102bfc66 0x10ff80000 + 3406950
15  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100df977 0x10ff80000 + 1440119
16  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100e988a 0x10ff80000 + 1480842
17  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110661338 0x10ff80000 + 7213880
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 10:: b-torcontrol
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e84fe poll + 10
1   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110ed9347 0x10ff80000 + 16094023
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110ed2c18 0x10ff80000 + 16067608
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011025ed15 0x10ff80000 + 3009813
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100fe6b7 0x10ff80000 + 1566391
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110265d1e 0x10ff80000 + 3038494
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: b-net
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202ea1fe __select + 10
1   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100fd014 0x10ff80000 + 1560596
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100fd6cb 0x10ff80000 + 1562315
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100fe49d 0x10ff80000 + 1565853
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ddfc3 0x10ff80000 + 1433539
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001101142ca 0x10ff80000 + 1655498
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 12:: b-addcon
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff2027dd83 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 93
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110113993 0x10ff80000 + 1653139
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011030db5e 0x10ff80000 + 3726174
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110103592 0x10ff80000 + 1586578
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ddfc3 0x10ff80000 + 1433539
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001101142ca 0x10ff80000 + 1655498
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 13:: b-opencon
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e48e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316e6f _pthread_cond_wait + 1254
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff2027dd83 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 93
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110113993 0x10ff80000 + 1653139
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011030db5e 0x10ff80000 + 3726174
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110101bb1 0x10ff80000 + 1579953
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110114bed 0x10ff80000 + 1657837
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ddfc3 0x10ff80000 + 1433539
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001101142ca 0x10ff80000 + 1655498
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 14:: b-msghand
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e40c6 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203142c5 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 81
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203121bc _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 211
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff202ab8f7 std::__1::recursive_mutex::lock() + 9
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011012128c 0x10ff80000 + 1708684
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011013555e 0x10ff80000 + 1791326
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001101038b9 0x10ff80000 + 1587385
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100ddfc3 0x10ff80000 + 1433539
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001101142ca 0x10ff80000 + 1655498
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 15:: QThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e40c6 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203142c5 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 81
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff203121bc _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 211
3   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff202ab8f7 std::__1::recursive_mutex::lock() + 9
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001100be46d 0x10ff80000 + 1303661
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000010ffb1425 0x10ff80000 + 201765
6   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x000000011081e23f 0x10ff80000 + 9036351
7   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110822612 0x10ff80000 + 9053714
8   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110818396 0x10ff80000 + 9012118
9   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110880a8d 0x10ff80000 + 9439885
10  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110881d18 0x10ff80000 + 9444632
11  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001107ff724 0x10ff80000 + 8910628
12  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110837e14 0x10ff80000 + 9141780
13  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001108362b0 0x10ff80000 + 9134768
14  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001107fb65f 0x10ff80000 + 8894047
15  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106db77c 0x10ff80000 + 7714684
16  org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106de900 0x10ff80000 + 7727360
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 16:: QThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff202e84fe poll + 10
1   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110834d40 0x10ff80000 + 9129280
2   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x0000000110836167 0x10ff80000 + 9134439
3   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001107fb65f 0x10ff80000 + 8894047
4   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106db77c 0x10ff80000 + 7714684
5   org.bitcoinfoundation.Bitcoin-Qt    0x00000001106de900 0x10ff80000 + 7727360
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20316950 _pthread_start + 224
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2031247b thread_start + 15

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20312458 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000070000f5b0000  rcx: 0x000070000f5af338  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000009d0b  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000f5af360  rsp: 0x000070000f5af338
   r8: 0x0000000000000070   r9: 0x00000000000007fb  r10: 0x000070000f5b0000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000009d0b  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff202e8462  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0xffffffb096d1a024
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133

Thread 9 instruction stream not available.

Thread 9 last branch register state not available.
```

Comment: Bitcoin Core is known to have issues with external drives as usually the USB interface is a bit flaky and the drive can disconnect which causes data corruption. If you use an internal drive, do you run into this problem? The particular issue here is that the database on the external drive has become corrupted.

Comment: @AndrewChow Unfortunately I don't have enough space on my internal HD for a full node. Is there anything I could to improve the connection with my external drive?

I tried -reindex yesterday and it still crashed again.